# When I buy Overwatch for PC, does it come with a disc?

Tags: overwatch

I just want to know so when I get it, I won't be confused. Also, when you launch the game, will you have to make an account?

Comment: if it says it comes with a disk then it should say what that disk is

Comment: The Amazon version also comes with a CD, as I preordered the origins Edition through Amazon and received a CD in addition to a code to register it to an account

Comment: The only way to play the game is with an account

Answer (score 5):

You must have a Battle.net account in order to play Overwatch.   Think of it like Steam -- you must have a Steam account in order to buy a Steam code to link it to your account; the same will go for Overwatch.

Only physical copies of Overwatch purchased will have the CD -- digital editions do not.

As you can see from the image below, Blizzard only sells digital copies, while Amazon, Best Buy, and Gamestop sell physical versions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. The only way you can get the disc is in the shops. Blizzard do not sell the disc copy from their site.

Comment: Yeah! I was planning on getting the disc at my local GameStop. Thank you for your answer!